# Invalid Uri: The Uri scheme is too long. UriFormatException" In dynamics-CRM FetchXML

Tags: dynamics-crm, postman, fetchxml

I'm trying to query a **Dynamic-CRM** system using **FetchXML get request**.
The error: 
**"Invalid Uri: The Uri scheme is too long. UriFormatException"**
occurs when I'm using specific attributtes\filters. 
For example: 
When trying to use filter condition with "on-or-after" operator referring dateTime with time stamp. I'm getting:

The initial query is big and working, but event when I shorten the query and use a specific attribute, the error raise. I couldn't put my finger on the problem.
See my code, as example:
This is not working:

```
<filter>
  <condition attribute="scheduledend" operator="le" value="2020-03-16T10:23:30" />
</filter>
```

This is working, but witout time stamp:

```
<filter>
  <condition attribute="scheduledend" operator="on-or-before" value="03/16/2020" />
</filter>
```

Let me emphasize - The

```
<filter>
  <condition attribute="scheduledend" operator="le" value="2020-03-16T10:23:30" />
</filter>
```

**might work if I remove some query attributes or filters**  - so this is just an example - I couldn't find a pattern for working\not working.
What might be the root cause for this problem ?

Comment: I found the exact same strange and seemingly random problem, where once the parameters were over a certain length, colons in values would break the request and cause this error. What an odd bug! This thread saved me. Ta!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It strikes me that since the colon `:` is a normal part of an HTTP URI, the colons in the timestamp may be triggering the issue.
According to the [standard URL encoding](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.ASP), `:` encodes to `%3A`.
Maybe give that a shot.

Another consideration is that a single quote is a legal URL character but a double quote is [unsafe](https://perishablepress.com/stop-using-unsafe-characters-in-urls/), so maybe switch to single quotes inside the FetchXML:

`<condition attribute='scheduledend' operator='le' value='2020-03-16T10%3A23%3A30' />`

Comment: I found the exact same strange and seemingly random problem, where once the parameters were over a certain length, colons in values would break the request and cause this error. What an odd bug! This thread saved me. Thanks for such a good, correct guess! URL-encoding the colons resolved my problem too.